# Remove "Social Title" from order form in Prestashop?

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I have just downloaded and installed the latest version of Prestashop. And found out there is a Social Title-option in order checkout form.

I want to remove that. I have found how to remove the Mr and Mrs boxes. But the whole row and label "Social Title" remains.

Have tried to search on Google for an answer but can't find. Some answers refer to the addresses.tpl. But I think the templates might been changed since these threads.

In fact, I have tried to search for "social" in the whole template directory and can't find anything related to this.

The nearest I get is in the ../templates/customer/_partials/customer-form.tpl. And I think it's rendered where this is:

```
<section>
    {block "form_fields"}
      {foreach from=$formFields item="field"}
        {block "form_field"}
          {form_field field=$field}
        {/block}
      {/foreach}
    {/block}
  </section>
```

So, maybe the social title isn't able to change from templates anymore?

So, where do I change it nowadays?

Comment: Which version? 1.7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shop Parameters -> Customer Settings -> Titles - Delete titles
themes/xxx/templates/_partials/form-fields.tpl 9th line change

```
  {if $field.type !== 'checkbox'}
    {$field.label}
  {/if}
```

to

```
  {if $field.type !== 'checkbox' and $field.type !== 'radio-buttons'}
    {$field.label}
  {/if}
```

Yeah, it's kind of dummy workaround, but it works.

UPDATE:
More proper way would be to comment the block:

```
        $genderField = (new FormField)
        ->setName('id_gender')
        ->setType('radio-buttons')
        ->setLabel(
            $this->translator->trans(
                'Social title', [], 'Shop.Forms.Labels'
            )
        )
    ;
    foreach (Gender::getGenders($this->language->id) as $gender) {
        $genderField->addAvailableValue($gender->id, $gender->name);
    }
    $format[$genderField->getName()] = $genderField;
```

You can find it in /classes/form/CustomerFormatter.php

Answer (score 3):

In Prestashop 1.7 there is no need to edit any code, you can just go to *Shop Parameters -> Customer Settings -> Titles* and remove all existing titles.

This will prevent the "Social title" field from being generated.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the code for Social Titles in file at the following path:

/themes/default-bootstrap/identity.tpl

Note: It is not a good practice to remove the code from a core file, we recommend to apply some CSS to hide the Social Title block.

Comment: Sadly there's no CSS markup for these form rows. So it can't be done from CSS.